# application-<sha1>.js gets redownloaded every request (tips to optimize caching)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, deployment, nginx, unicorn

I just realize that application.css & .js & fonts files on my rails application always gets redownloaded every time I change page. This causes quite a burden on the server and slowing the loading times.

Can anyone here recommend me on how to optimize caching, preferably best practices that I can follow because frankly I'm not very experienced in deployment optimization.

ps: I already read and done some of the tips from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html but the assets still gets redownloaded..

edited: my nginx configuration

```
upstream example_com {
  server unix:/tmp/example_com.todo.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/example.com/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @example_com;

  location @example_com {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://example_com;
  }

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

  access_log /var/www/example_com/shared/log/access.log main;
  error_log /var/www/example_com/shared/log/error.log info;
}
```

cache header, got this from firebug:

```
Response Headers From Cache
Cache-Control   max-age=31536000, public
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    application/x-javascript
Date    Wed, 04 Jul 2012 09:45:51 GMT
Expires Thu, 04 Jul 2013 09:45:51 GMT
Last-Modified   Wed, 04 Jul 2012 05:52:38 GMT
Server  nginx/1.2.1
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Sorry for the obvious questions, but can you confirm that you're running in the production RIALS_ENV / RACK_ENV and that the server isn't responding with a 304 (not modified)?

Comment: yes, I ran it on production environment..

Comment: can you confirm that nginx is serving up the static files rather than rails, and that your browser is seeing the cache headers?

Comment: I think so yes, I posted the cache header above.. but how can I check whether nginx is the one that serve the static files?

Comment: nginx is definitely setting the cache header, but you can also check both the nginx and the rails logs to see who's doing what. Is it possible that you have the cache disabled in firefox (e.g., http://superuser.com/questions/23134/how-to-turn-off-firefox-cache)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling your assets (`rake assets:precompile` or deploying to an environment like heroku), then these will just be static files like `application-8675309.....js`, which should be served up by your web server. Make sure that whatever web server you're using knows to serve up files in your public/assets directory instead of having those requests go through rails. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production for some sample server configurations to accomplish this.

Comment: yes, I already precompiled my assets and set serve static assets to false in production configuration.. Unfortunately I still got 200 response instead of 304..

Comment: the fact that you said it's serving up application.js and not application-<sha1>.js to me signals that at least that asset isn't getting compiled. Do you have `config.assets.enabled = true` in your application.rb?

Comment: Oh sorry for that, yes what i meant is application-<sha1>.js.. not application.js. should be "the application-<sha1>.js gets redownloaded".. I type application.js for simplicity purpose..

Comment: what are you using for the web server, and can you paste the relevant part of your server configuration?

Comment: I use nginx for web server, and I put my nginx configuration on my edited question..